# Android Overscroll empty Listview

Tags: android, listview, overscroll

Im new to android and making a listview with overscroll option, my idea is pull the listview to refresh it , first of all i need to learn how to make a listview overscroll without any items in it. 
Please give me some solutions , yes ofcourse ive googled about my problem however there were libraries given , 
I just only wanted to understand how and make my own listview , i dont wanna copy any library thats all.
Thank you !

Comment: You don't want to copy any library that is fine.. did not you stumble upon some example code while googling?

Comment: First of all you have try some from your end and if you get any problem then ask SO otherwise no one here to do all code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400248/tap-to-refresh-is-visible-all-the-time-and-gap-is-still-visible-on-list-view)

or

You can directly download the source code [from git hub](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

You need to include this class `PullToRefreshListView extends ListView`

Then you need to add that in xml `.PullToRefreshListView`